# Why do my shadows look like this in opentk c#?

Tags: c#, opentk

I wanted to add shadows to my opentk project, and I did some research and attempted to write some code, but once I finished it, the shadows appeared like this. I have no clue what I did wrong.

[shadows not right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDIVD.png)

code:

```
 public enum LightType
 {
     Directional,
     Point,
     Spot
 }

 internal class LightSource
 {
     public Vector3 Position { get; set; }
     public Vector3 Rotation { get; set; }
     public float Intensity { get; set; }
     public LightType Type { get; set; }

     public LightSource(Vector3 position, Vector3 rotation, float intensity, LightType type)
     {
         Position = position;
         Rotation = rotation;
         Intensity = intensity;
         Type = type;
     }

     public Matrix4 CalculateLightSpaceMatrix(Vector3 sceneCenter)
     {
         Matrix4 lightViewMatrix;
         Matrix4 lightProjectionMatrix;
         if (Type == LightType.Directional)
         {
             Vector3 lightDirection = Vector3.Transform(Vector3.UnitZ, Quaternion.FromEulerAngles(Rotation));

             float distance = 10.0f; 
             Position = sceneCenter - lightDirection * distance;

             lightViewMatrix = Matrix4.LookAt(Position, sceneCenter, Vector3.UnitY);

             float orthoSize = 20.0f;
             float nearPlane = 1.0f;
             float farPlane = 500.0f;
             lightProjectionMatrix = Matrix4.CreateOrthographic(orthoSize, orthoSize, nearPlane, farPlane);

             return lightViewMatrix * lightProjectionMatrix;
         }
         else if (Type == LightType.Point)
         {
   
         }
         else if (Type == LightType.Spot)
         {

         }

         return Matrix4.Identity; 
     }
 }
```

```
        protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs args)
        {

            GL.ClearColor(0.3f, 0.3f, 1f, 1f);
            GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
            Matrix4 model = Matrix4.Identity;
            Matrix4 view = c.getViewMatrix();
            Matrix4 projection = c.getProjectionMatrix();

            int modelLocation = GL.GetUniformLocation(program.ID, "model");
            int viewLocation = GL.GetUniformLocation(program.ID, "view");
            int projectionLocation = GL.GetUniformLocation(program.ID, "projection");

            GL.UniformMatrix4(modelLocation, true, ref model);
            GL.UniformMatrix4(viewLocation, true, ref view);
            GL.UniformMatrix4(projectionLocation, true, ref projection);

            GL.UniformMatrix4(GL.GetUniformLocation(depthMapShader.ID, "lightSpaceMatrix"), true, ref lightSpaceMatrix);
            RenderDepthMapPass();

            GL.UniformMatrix4(GL.GetUniformLocation(program.ID, "lightSpaceMatrix"), true, ref lightSpaceMatrix);
            GL.Uniform1(GL.GetUniformLocation(program.ID, "diffuseTexture"), 0);
            GL.Uniform1(GL.GetUniformLocation(program.ID, "shadowMap"), 1);

            GL.ActiveTexture(TextureUnit.Texture1);
            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, depthMapTexture);

            chunk.Render(program);
            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0);
            GL.DeleteTexture(depthMapTexture);

            Context.SwapBuffers();
        }

        void RenderDepthMapPass()
        {
            GL.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, depthMapFBO);
            GL.Viewport(0, 0, width, height);
            GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

            Matrix4 chunkMatrix = Matrix4.CreateTranslation(chunk.position);
            GL.UniformMatrix4(GL.GetUniformLocation(depthMapShader.ID, "model"), true, ref chunkMatrix);
            chunk.Render(depthMapShader);

            GL.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, 0);
        }
    void SetupDepthMapFBO(int width, int height)
    {
        GL.GenFramebuffers(1, out depthMapFBO);
        GL.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, depthMapFBO);

        GL.GenTextures(1, out depthMapTexture);
        GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, depthMapTexture);
        GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.DepthComponent,
                      width, height, 0, OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4.PixelFormat.DepthComponent, PixelType.Float, IntPtr.Zero);
        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Nearest);
        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Nearest);
        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS, (int)TextureWrapMode.ClampToEdge);
        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, (int)TextureWrapMode.ClampToEdge);

        GL.FramebufferTexture2D(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, FramebufferAttachment.DepthAttachment,
                                TextureTarget.Texture2D, depthMapTexture, 0);

        GL.DrawBuffer(DrawBufferMode.None);
        GL.ReadBuffer(ReadBufferMode.None);

        GL.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, 0);
    }
   protected override void OnLoad()
   {
       base.OnLoad();

       chunk = new Chunk(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));

       program = new ShaderProgram("default.vert", "default.frag");
       depthMapShader = new ShaderProgram("LightSource.vert","LightSource.frag");

       GL.Enable(EnableCap.CullFace);
       GL.CullFace(CullFaceMode.Back);
       GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);

       c = new camera(width, height, Vector3.Zero);
       CursorState = CursorState.Grabbed;

       Vector3 lightPosition = new Vector3(20.0f, 8.0f, 20.0f);
       Vector3 lightRotation = new Vector3(-45.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
       float lightIntensity = 1.0f;
       LightType lightType = LightType.Directional;

       light = new LightSource(lightPosition, lightRotation, lightIntensity, lightType);

       Vector3 sceneCenter = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); 
       lightSpaceMatrix = light.CalculateLightSpaceMatrix(sceneCenter);
       
   }
```

I tried changing orders of some calculations to see if they were typed wrong, but I couldn't find anything.